# How to find out what number this div tag in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{myBookmarks.map((myBookmark) => (
  <div
    className={classes.item}
    key={myBookmark.id}
    onClick={clickHandler}
  >
    <img src={myBookmark.icon} alt={icon} />
    <div className={classes.text}>
      <div>{myBookmark.title}</div>
      <div className={classes.url}>{myBookmark.url}</div>
    </div>
    <div className={classes.image} Click={updateEditModalHadler}>
      <GoKebabVertical />
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

i want to access myBookmark.id or key value in a updateEditModalHadler

i'm trying to find out what number this div tag is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `updateEditModalHadler` a higher-order function, one which takes the ID as a parameter and returns the click handler function.

```
<div className={classes.image} onClick={makeUpdateEditModalHandler(myBookmark.id)}>
```

```
const makeUpdateEditModalHandler = (id) => (e) => {
  // rest of handler function
};
```

Comment: function updateEditModalHandler(id, e) {
} 
what is the difference?

Comment: No, using this method, the ID needs to be passed in a prior function, not an additional argument

Comment: function updateEditModalHandler(id) {
return function updateEditModalHandler2(e) { 
}
}

Comment: Yeah, you can do that too, but currying with the arrow function is more concise and easier to read IMO